# Поиск в ListView fragment из Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Есть `Activity` с `TabLayout`. В `TabLayout` `Fragments` со списком `(ListView)`. В каждом списке заполнены списки данными. В `Activity` в шапке есть searchView.(поиск). При наборе список должен фильтроваться динамически. 
И так что сделано.

1. Реализовано все без `Activity`. Ниже код.

   ```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_song, menu);

           MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
           SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
           searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

           return true;
       }

   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
           artistAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
           return true;
       }
   ```
2. Фильтр в адаптере написан.
3. Список имеет данные и фильтруется.

Так вот, это реализовано в одном `Activity` Без `Fragments`, а как реализовать с фрагментами это чудо. Что бы в `Activity` в `Searchview` я вбивал, а во `Fragment` фильтровался список.

p.s. Чувствую, что решение связано с интерфейсами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо того что бы инфлейтить меню в *Activity* лучше делать это непосредственно в *Fragment*-e. Даже если в *Activity* есть данные необходимые для поиска, что очень редко бывает, то из фрагмента несложно их получить.

А вот поисковую логику для фрагмента лучше реализовать в нём самом. Для этого нужно сделать следующие вещи:

**сказать фрагменту, чтобы он отображал меню**:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);//для этого преднозначен этот метод
    //Ваш код
}
```

**Реализовать методы для создания меню**

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_song, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    artistAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    return true;
}
```

Обратите внимание метод *onCreateOptionsMenu*  различается сигнатурой с анологичным методом из *Activity*.

Осталось только во фрагменте реализовать необходимые листенеры.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно вы чувствуете, решение с интерфейсами связано, если в обратную сторон (передавать инфу от фрагмента к Activity), а Activity общается с фрагментом через Bundle, но это будет не кошерно. А решение для вас очень простое, вы посмотрите функции класса Fragment, в методо **public void onAttach(Activity activity)**, который вы можете переопределить вы получаете Activity, там вы можете получить по ID ваш searchView, а далее прицепить к нему обработчик и всё, плов готов